# Copy a view definition from one database to another one in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I am developping a script that allows me to create all the views present in `database1` in another database (`database2`).

I am trying to do that using a cursor that loop on all the views of `database1` and then try to execute the definition of that view on the second database.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the following error:

> Syntaxe incorrecte vers 'go'.
>   Msg 111, Niveau 15, État 1, Ligne 14
>   'CREATE VIEW' doit être la première instruction d'un traitement de requêtes.

This is my code

```
declare @database2 varchar(50), @database1 varchar(50)
set @database2 = 'Local'
set @database1 = 'prod'

declare @Query nvarchar(max), @view_definition nvarchar(max), @count int

set @count = 0

declare curseur cursor for SELECT top 1 view_definition FROM prod.information_schema.VIEWS 
open curseur
fetch curseur into  @view_definition
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    set @count = @count + 1
    --Print 'Vue N° ' + cast(@count as varchar) + ':'
    set @Query = N'Use ' + @database2 +CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+ 'go' + @view_definition +CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+ 'go'
    print @Query
    exec sp_executesql @Query
    fetch curseur into  @view_definition
End
Close curseur
deallocate curseur
```

This code was executed from database1.

However when I execute the result of the 'print @Query' instruction, it works!!

Does anyone can help me to resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just generate `CREATE` scripts of the views in the first DB and execute in the second DB?

Comment: Can you translate *doit être la première instruction d'un traitement de requêtes* please?

Comment: this expression in french means that the instruction create view has to be at the first position in a process

Comment: Can you show what your print statement displays?

Comment: hello steve, this is the print statement display: --Vue N° 1:
Use wi_vigicolisLocal
go
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PlateformeCollaborative]
AS
 select rc.category_id,cc.category_name rc.RCode_Text
 from  rcode rc left join rcodeprocessing rcp on rc.rcode_id=rcp.rcode_id
 inner join categorycontent cc on rc.category_id=cc.category_id and language_id='FR'
 inner join rshipper rs on rc.rshipper_id=rs.rshipper_id
 where rcp.RCodeProcessing_ID is null

go. The go clause is on a new line alone

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here:

1. You can't USE another database in a stored procedure, although is the other database is on the same server you can use `CREATE VIEW databasename.schemaname.viewname (...`. If it's on another server, yiu could try setting it up as a linked server and using servername.database.schema.viewname.
2. sp_executesql expects one statement, and doesn't accept GO to my
   knowledge (which is what the error is telling you). You could try to
   put in ';' instead (and you don't need the CHAR(13)'s if you do
   although they make it easier to read).

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone in the future, here's my solution to this problem. The full history of how I came up with it is over at [Stored Procedure to Copy Views from Current Database to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64877998/stored-procedure-to-copy-views-from-current-database-to-another)

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Copy_View_To_Database]
    @ViewName SYSNAME, -- The name of the view to copy over
    @DatabaseName SYSNAME, -- The name of the database to copy the view to    
    @overwrite bit = 1 -- Whether to overwrite any existing view
AS
    IF DB_ID(@DatabaseName) IS NULL -- Validate the database name exists
    BEGIN
       RAISERROR('Invalid Destination Database Name passed',16,1)
       RETURN
    END    
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF @overwrite = 1 -- If set to overwrite, try to drop the remote view
    BEGIN    
        DECLARE @DropViewStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) =
            'EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + '.sys.sp_executesql N''DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ' + QUOTENAME(@ViewName) + ';'';'
        EXEC (@DropViewStatement);
    END
    -- Extract the saved definition of the view
    DECLARE @ViewDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @ViewDefinition = definition FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@ViewName);
    -- Check for a mismatch between the internal view name and the expected name (TODO: Resolve this automatically?)
    IF @ViewDefinition NOT LIKE ('%' + @ViewName + '%')
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @InternalName NVARCHAR(MAX) = SUBSTRING(@ViewDefinition, 3, CHARINDEX(char(10), @ViewDefinition, 3)-4);
       PRINT ('Warning: The view named '+@ViewName+' has an internal definition name that is different ('+@InternalName+'). This may have been caused by renaming the view after it was created. You will have to drop and recreate it with the correct name.')
    END
    -- Substitute any hard-coded references to the current database with the destination database
    SET @ViewDefinition = REPLACE(@ViewDefinition, db_name(), @DatabaseName); 
    -- Generate the dynamic SQL that will create the view on the remote database
    DECLARE @CreateViewStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) =
        'EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + '.sys.sp_executesql N''' + REPLACE(@ViewDefinition,'''','''''') + ''';'
    --PRINT '@CreateViewStatement: ' + @CreateViewStatement -- Can be used for debugging
    -- Execute the create statement
    EXEC (@CreateViewStatement);
```

In short, you need two layers of nested dynamic SQL:

- Inner layer to execute the "CREATE VIEW" statement, which must be on its own. This is executed using `EXEC SomeDatabase.sys.sp_executesql @CreateViewSQL`
- One more layer to dynamically specify "SomeDatabase" via a parameter (assuming you require the flexibility of copying it to a database not known at scripting time).

Calling the above stored proc in the inner-loop of the original poster's tentative solution should solve the problem of copying a view to another database.

Note that simply looping over all views might pose a challenge if views depend on one another. There may be some additional complexity involving resolving the dependency tree of views an copying them in the correct order. Alternatively, a "dumb and easy" approach might be to loop over all views, ignore failures, and keep repeating the process until all views have been created.